# c++ calling functions from c#-dll fails

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I wrote a c# (net 3.5) dll and exported some functions via Robert Giesecke's "Unmanaged Exports":

```
[DllExport("VersionString", CallingConvention =
CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 

public static string VersionString() { .... return "test"; }
```

Then I wrote a c++ wrapper for my c#-dll. In c++ I call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to get a reference to a c#-function.

I can call the function an get a return value. Works like a charm.

```
HINSTANCE hJConnectInstance = LoadLibrary(L"JConnect.Base.dll");

typedef char *(__cdecl *func_i)();

func_i net_function = (func_i)GetProcAddress(hJConnectInstance, VersionString");

std::string result = std::string(net_function());

std::cout << "csharp result: " << result << std::endl;
```

But my goal was to return a JSON string from .net and so I added Newtonsoft.json to my c# project.

Now everytime I call the c# function from my wrapper I get an error in c++.
The error is not in the c# code because it works when called from another c# project.

I can't even tell what kind of error is thrown in c++, because I don't know how to properly catch it. (I am a c++ noob)

Questions:

- What could be the reason that the call to the c# function fails when
  additional libraries are added to the c# project?
- How can I properly catch the error in my c++ project?

Thank you!

Comment: Why is my question downvoted?

Comment: You can use  `DllImport` C# runtime attribute instead of `GPA`, you might catch an error that way.

Comment: This is a generic problem with the "unmanaged exports" utility, managed code likes to throw exceptions but you're blind as a bat when it happens.  Turning very simple problems into undebuggable ones.  Right-click your C++ project > Properties > Debugging > "Debugger Type" = Mixed.  And Debug > Windows > Exceptions Settings, tick the checkbox for CLR Exceptions.  And Tools > Options > Debugging > General > untick "Just My Code".  The debugger should now stop when the exception is thrown.  Probably something silly like FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Bam! Thats why i love stackoverflow! Post some weird problem and immediately get pushed on the right track! Thanks Hans! See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comment from Hans Passant I found the problem.
I was able to get a error message that notified me that one of my referenced dll's diddn't have a strong name.
Correcting that solved the issues.

Thanks!